# Strange behavior of ArcTan

Tags: evaluation, trigonometry

I've noticed a strange behavior of Mathematica's [`ArcTan`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArcTan.html) function with two arguments. If both arguments are `0` or `0.`, Mathematica evaluates the `ArcTan` to `Indeterminate`.

```
ArcTan[0, 0]
```

> ```
> During evaluation of In[1]:= ArcTan::indet: Indeterminate expression ArcTan[0,0] encountered. >>
> Indeterminate
> ```

```
ArcTan[0., 0.]
```

> ```
> During evaluation of In[2]:= ArcTan::indet: Indeterminate expression ArcTan[0.,0.] encountered. >>
> Indeterminate
> ```

However, I get different results if only one argument is using machine precision:

```
ArcTan[0., 0]
```

> ```
> 0
> ```

```
ArcTan[0, 0.]
```

> ```
> π/2
> ```

No warning is displayed.
This inconsistent behavior is causing problems in my code. Is it a bug or is it intentional? Why does this happen?

Answer (score 1):

To Mathematica, 0. means "somewhere in the vicinity of zero". 0 means "exactly zero", much stronger. So, when you mix them, the stronger condition wins.